# Error in breakpoint condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints, lldb

I've set a breakpoint with the condition...

```
[event.name isEqualToString:@"Some Name"]
```

This works fine.

However, when I try to add another breakpoint with the condition...

```
[part.name isEqualToString:@"Some Value With A Pound Sign £"]
```

I get the error...

```
Internal error [IRForTarget]: An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint
```

Do I need to escape the pound sign or something?

Comment: It doesn't create an error if I remove the £... but it also doesn't pause.

Comment: try `[part.name rangeOfString:@"Some Value With A Pound Sign"].location != NSNotFound;`  Unless you are specifically looking for the pound sign, then you'll have to look into strings using different encoding.

Comment: That looks like a bug in LLDB (encoding problem) and you should report it to Apple.

Comment: @Putz1103 I tried that but got... `Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 12.1: "[part.name rangeOfString:@"Search String"].location != NSNotFound;"
error: 'rangeOfString:' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression`

Comment: @Fogmeister I've tried same thing and put a breakpoint on that line as u but I haven't found any such error.
My code: if ([self.strCheck isEqualToString:@"Some Value With A Pound Sign £"])
    {
        NSLog(@"get");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not");
    }

Comment: It seems that the expression parser in LLDB generally has a problem with non-ASCII characters. `po @"abc"` in the debugger console works, but `po @"ä"` or `po @"€"` fail with a similar message.

Comment: You just have to cast each method's return type to fix that.

Comment: @GianlucaTranchedone could you explain how to do that in the breakpoint condition please. (Possibly in an answer that I can accept)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a bug with the expression parser and an NSString literal containing non-ASCII characters.

```
(lldb) po @"u"
$9 = 0x00007fff7debe5e0 u
(lldb) po @"ü"
Internal error [IRForTarget]: An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array
error: warning: expression result unused
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

There is already a bug reported filed with http://bugreport.apple.com/ about this issue.

Non-ASCII C string literals are handled correctly so it is possible to work around this, e.g.

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"ü"]
$11 = 0x000000010010b040 ü
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the breakpoints have still such a limited compiler support, but anyway, to fix your problem, it should be sufficient to cast the return type of each method you call like this:

```
(BOOL)[(NSString *)[part name] isEqualToString:@"some string"]
```

With this your code should pause if the string doesn't contain the '£' symbol or any other non-ASCII character. As it appears that the LLDB compiler has problems non-ASCII characters you may want to convert the strings first using that encoding. In the mean while I'm looking for a way to avoid this if possible…

Comment: The problem occurs if "some string" contains non-ASCII characters. Casting to `NSString *` did not help in my test case.

Comment: No, didn't help for me either. Sorry.

Comment: Oh yeah, I noticed. Well, at least his code should pause when there's no non-ASCII character. Let's try to find a solution for that!

Comment: Amazing! This solved my problem with conditional breakpoints!