# UTF8String throws error: Internal error [IRForTarget]: An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring

When I use the function `[oriStr UTF8String]`, there comes an issue.
This is the `lldb print` :

```
(lldb) po oriStr
四川省-成都市

(lldb) po [oriStr UTF8String]
<no value available>

(lldb) po [@"你好" UTF8String]
Internal error [IRForTarget]: An Objective-C constant string's string initializer is not an array
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

And yestoday is okay, but today it run into trouble.I don't know why.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192505/error-in-breakpoint-condition/17248200#17248200

Answer (score 0):

po used to print object， use [oriStr UTF8String] oriStr will be C string